# Spring boot rest api - connection reset?

Tags: spring, rest, connection, reset

I need a spring boot example that needs to be generate the "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" Error.

Answer (score 0):

Why a whole `spring-boot` project to throw an exception?

```
public static void main( String args[] ){
    try{
       doThrowSocketException(); 
    }catch{
        //Handle the exception
    }
    
}

private void doThrowSocketException() throws SocketException{
    throw new SocketException();
}
```